# Finding $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{x^2}\,dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I was wondering if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{x^2}\,dx$ is defined, I think it isn't. But I dunno how to start proving/disproving.

Comment: Try looking at the graph of $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: I did that, but how to I prove it mathematically? @user1337

Comment: $e^{x^2} \ge 1$, and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1 dx = ...?$

Comment: take $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x^2+y^2}dydx$,
use polar cordinate to find it,
since by properties of double integral and exponential function
we have $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x^2}dx.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{y^2}dy$.then proceed

Comment: You could also observe $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x^2}\;dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{x^2}\;dx$. Then comparing to its Riemann sum as an approximation, it cannot converge as $\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{x^2} \neq 0$. You could moreover compare $2\int_0^\infty e^{x^2}dx$ to $\int_0^\infty 2^x dx$ etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, notice that $e^{x^2}\geq 1$ for all $x$ so that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x^2}\;dx \geq \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1 \; dx
$$